# Security best practice when running process as non-root user

Tags: linux, security, permissions, root, supervisord

So I'm trying to run Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/) as a non-root user. However the process outputs logs to the `/var/log` directory which is owned by root and has 755 permissions. Therefore starting the process as a non-root user throws a permission denied error. What is a best practice for solving this issue? One idea I have is to recursively change the group of the `/var` directory to that of the user which is starting the supervisor process, and giving the `/var` directory 775 permissions. Is this acceptable from a security standpoint?

Answer (score 4):

Try creating the log files and using `chown` to change the ownership to the appropriate user.  If possible change the log location to a subdirectory owned by the appropriate user.

I use `logrotate` to rotate logs periodically.  It can handle permissions when rotating logs.

Comment: So you will typically move the logs to a subdirectory of that user's home?

Comment: I would move the logs to a subdirectory of /var/log.  In this case /var/log/supervisord.

Comment: But doesn't that user need permissions to access `/var/log` then?

Comment: No, the user just needs `write` access to `/var/log/supervisord`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `user=` directive in `supervisord.conf`, so that supervisord starts as root, does any necessary opening of files, and then drops privileges.

Comment: How do I get supervisord to drop privileges?

Comment: By setting the `user` parameter, as I just said.

Comment: but if I have `user=root` in the config file, doesn't the user remain as `root`?

Comment: Why would you do that?! Aren't you trying to run it as a different user?

Comment: I'm confused haha. Yes I do want to run it as a different user. Right now I have `user=[non-root user]` already and that is what's causing the problem

Comment: You forgot to mention that in your question. At this point you should probably contact the developers.

Comment: Why? Isn't that expected behavior if the process is run as a non-root user? How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you could create a user specifically to run supervisord, and use an ACL to give that user write privileges in /var/log.

```
setfacl -m u:$USER:rwx /var/log
```

You can also do things like make your supervisord user a member of sys. (I think, I don't have a linux box nearby to verify that the /var/log group has write privileges.)